# Android file parser

Tags: java, android, parsing, ini

I have following file/string/data.I want to parse it in key value pair for core java or Android.It is ".ini" file,but parser like ini4j,java Properties class are not working for this.Can anybody please help in selecting parser and Implementing steps.

```
version = "1.5";
client = "demo";
key2 = "Key2_value";
Providers = ( 
  {
    Name = "DEMO_PROVIDER";
    Version = 3845678;
    key3="key_3_value"
    PAs = [ "Pa value 1", "Pa value 2", "Pa value 3" ];
    LogLevel = "DEBUG";
    Server = "www.stackoverflow.com";
    Services = ( 
      {
        Percent = 10;
        certFormat = "text";
        key4 = false;
        key5 = "KEY5_NAME";
        Uri = "www.stackoverflow.com";
        Key6= "No";
        key7= "R11";
        Users = [ "swapnil@test.local" ];
      } );
  } );
```

Which parser is to be used for this kind of file.

Comment: Is it possible to use a standard Java properties file or a format other than `.ini`?

Comment: No Properties file we can't use we need to use same format.

Comment: Only we to implement this is use of custom inline parser